# Delete Derby entries

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I use JPA to add data to Derby DB with eclipse link and when there is duplicated ID.

I got error, there is a way in **run-time** (with code) to simple delete all the table entries.

I don't need the old entry just new entries in every time that I invoke the program.

I tried with

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Job p ");

List resultList = query.getResultList();

for (Object result : resultList) {
    entityManager.remove(result);
}

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

but here I use query before and I don't want to do that I want to delete **all the entries** and I don't care what is there before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL DELETE query at runtime everytime the application starts. If you don't post some code, we can't help.

**EDIT :**

You can execute the query as follows in some earlier transaction or the same transaction before the query:

```
int deletedCount = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Job").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi ,I tried like your suggestion and I got error ,this is my new code      String className = object.getClass().getName();
   entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
   entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + className).executeUpdate();
   entityManager.persist(object);
   entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: the error is:javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/vogella/databases/simpleDb' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@558fe7c3, see the next exception for details.
Error Code: 40000
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602)

Comment: This is starnge since when i run it on the debugger it's run well and when I run it regular I got this message...

Comment: Your error should be occurring on factory.createEntityManager(); and have nothing to do with the query. Check that your persistence.xml is correct and that you can connect to the derby database.  Show the full exception stack trace otherwise and how you have configured the DB to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could either execute a delete query, or configure your persistence unit to recreate the tables when the persistence unit is deployed.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm#BABHEJJI